# how to create a checkbox that need to pass string value?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-2

i want to create a check box and that should have to string value?

```
<%:Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.bird)%>
<%:Html.LabelFor(model=>model.bird) %>
```

i get a error saying string cannot convert to bool?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the bird member of your model **is not a boolean type**.

Add a new bool member (birdBool) to your model. This member can be as follow:

```
public bool birdBool
{
   get{
      try
      {
         return bool.Parse(this.bird);
      }
      catch{
         return false;
      }
   }
   set{
      this.bird=value.ToString();
   }
}
```

In your view write this:

```
<%:Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.birdBool)%>
<%:Html.LabelFor(model=>model.bird) %>
```

Comment: yeah..i know..because i want to pass string value not boolean

Comment: Your string have the value "True" or "False"?